# Using the number of days to delete the duplicate records in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sql-delete

What I am trying to do her in enrollment month column, row 14,15 is deleting the duplicate by keeping the more enrollment days. (In SQL Oracle)

```
        ID    Name   TermStartDate TermEndDate EnrollmentMonths
    1   1   John Smith  20180201    20180331    20180201
    2   1   John Smith  20180201    20180331    20180301
    3   1   John Smith  20180801    20180831    20180801
    4   1   John Smith  20180901    20180930    20180901
    5   1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20181001
    6   1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20181101
    7   1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20181201
    8   1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190101
    9   1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190201
    10  1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190301
    11  1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190401
    12  1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190501
    13  1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190601
    14  1   John Smith  20181001    20190701    20190701
    15  1   Catherine   20190702    20191130    20190701
    16  1   Catherine   20190702    20191130    20190801
    17  1   Catherine   20190702    20191130    20190901
    18  1   Catherine   20190702    20191130    20191001
    19  1   Catherine   20190702    20191130    20191101
```

To illustrate,
row 14: John Smith enrolled only one day in July
while Catherine in row 15 enrolled 30 days. From there I want to delete row 14 and keep row 15.

I am having difficult time making this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
delete from mytable t
where  least(termenddate, last_day(enrollmentmonths)) - greatest(termstartdate, enrollmentmonths) < (
    select max(least(t1.termenddate, last_day(t1.enrollmentmonths)) - greatest(t1.termstartdate, t1.enrollmentmonths)) 
    from mytable t1
    where t1.enrollmentmonths = t.enrollmentmonths
)
```

When there is more than one row for a given enrollment month, this deletes the one that has less days in the month. If there are ties, both are retained.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0f9a55728da0d65f650c13461a0124b5)**:

```
 ID | NAME       | TERMSTARTDATE | TERMENDDATE | ENROLLMENTMONTHS
 -: | :--------- | :------------ | :---------- | :---------------
  1 | John Smith | 20180201      | 20180331    | 20180201        
  1 | John Smith | 20180201      | 20180331    | 20180301        
  1 | John Smith | 20180801      | 20180831    | 20180801        
  1 | John Smith | 20180901      | 20180930    | 20180901        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181001        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181101        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181201        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190101        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190201        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190301        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190401        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190501        
  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190601        
  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190701        
  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190801        
  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190901        
  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20191001        
  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20191101
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DENSE_RANK` (or `ROW_NUMBER`) analytic function to rank the rows with duplicate `EnrollmentMonths` in order of longest period within those months and then use the `ROWID` pseudo-column to efficiently correlate with the `DELETE`:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (
             PARTITION BY EnrollmentMonths
             ORDER BY LEAST( LAST_DAY( EnrollmentMonths ), TermEndDate )
                      - GREATEST( EnrollmentMonths, TermStartDate )
                      DESC
           ) AS rnk
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE rnk > 1
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( ID, Name, TermStartDate, TermEndDate, EnrollmentMonths ) AS
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-03-31', DATE '2018-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-02-01', DATE '2018-03-31', DATE '2018-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-08-01', DATE '2018-08-31', DATE '2018-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-09-01', DATE '2018-09-30', DATE '2018-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2018-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2018-11-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2018-12-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'John Smith', DATE '2018-10-01', DATE '2019-07-01', DATE '2019-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Catherine',  DATE '2019-07-02', DATE '2019-11-30', DATE '2019-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Catherine',  DATE '2019-07-02', DATE '2019-11-30', DATE '2019-08-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Catherine',  DATE '2019-07-02', DATE '2019-11-30', DATE '2019-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Catherine',  DATE '2019-07-02', DATE '2019-11-30', DATE '2019-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Catherine',  DATE '2019-07-02', DATE '2019-11-30', DATE '2019-11-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Which deletes one row and leaves the table as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

> ```
> ID | NAME       | TERMSTARTDATE | TERMENDDATE | ENROLLMENTMONTHS
> -: | :--------- | :------------ | :---------- | :---------------
>  1 | John Smith | 20180201      | 20180331    | 20180201        
>  1 | John Smith | 20180201      | 20180331    | 20180301        
>  1 | John Smith | 20180801      | 20180831    | 20180801        
>  1 | John Smith | 20180901      | 20180930    | 20180901        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181001        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181101        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20181201        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190101        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190201        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190301        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190401        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190501        
>  1 | John Smith | 20181001      | 20190701    | 20190601        
>  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190701        
>  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190801        
>  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20190901        
>  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20191001        
>  1 | Catherine  | 20190702      | 20191130    | 20191101
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0c82f75fb4de93385591cf9348330849)*

Comment: what if the term end date is 20190703

Comment: @B.Saleh Updated.